# nestjs to azure windows app service - web.config settings

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-web-app-service, nestjs

I've been trying to deploy my nestjs api to azure since yesterday and have not been successful.  At first I was trying to push it to a linux cloud service plan and was able to deploy it from vs code, see in the azure logs that the app was successfully started, but it would not return any data from my endpoints and after some digging, I kept seeing some container failures.  I tried troubleshooting that for a while then decided I would try setting it up on a windows app service instead.

Following this guide: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-get-started-nodejs, I pushed my nestjs app up to an azure app service on windows and again, it did not work.  I pulled down the repo in that article to compare it to mine and they have the entry point in the web.config for the nodejs app pointing to index.js.  That index.js doesn't exist in my nestjs app and I did some research and found out that the entry point for a nestjs app after everything is compiled is main.js.  There is another difference in that sample project and my nestjs app in that the nestjs app's main.js file appears to be in a dist folder, rather than at the root of the wwwroot path.

My nestjs app obviously didn't contain a web.config out of the box so I created one using the hello world repo's as an example.  I updated the iisnode path to dist/main.js and the rewrite path as well to the same path/file since that's the only thing I can think to do.

The only other wildcard is the node version number that I'm changing in azure for the WEBSITE_NODE_DEFAULT_VERSION application setting...I'm not sure what that should be for my nestjs app.  My current local version is 12.16.2 but when I change the version to that on azure, it doesn't work.

I'm not sure what else to try here - I'd be fine trying to go back to linux if I could sort out the docker container issue but that seemed like a dead end.  I think I'll likely have more luck continuing down the windows route if I can just get this web.config / version thing to work.

Is main.js in the dist folder where I should be pointing my web.config?  Is there a max version limit on azure?  Is there anything else I might be missing?

EDIT:  After turning on streaming logs - I'm now seeing this exception

> SyntaxError: Use of const in strict mode.
>       at Module._compile (module.js:434:25)
>       at Object..js (module.js:464:10)
>       at Module.load (module.js:353:31)
>       at Function._load (module.js:311:12)
>       at Module.require (module.js:359:17)
>       at require (module.js:375:17)
>       at Object. (D:\Program Files (x86)\iisnode\interceptor.js:459:1)
>       at Module._compile (module.js:446:26)
>       at Object..js (module.js:464:10)
>       at Module.load (module.js:353:31)

after some googling, I've found that exception was common with older versions of node (< 4).  I'm well beyond that version and have azure set to a version well beyond that as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it sorted out with the help of a friend.  Running this in the azure cli got things sorted out using the linux setup.

```
az webapp config set --resource-group myResourceGroup --name myAppServiceName --startup-file "npm run start:prod"
```

Comment: Same thing I said in my comment . Running that CLI command is the same as adding the `npm run start` to Startup Command under General Settings in the Configuration blade.

Comment: @RyanHill-MSFT I created an app under linux and windows, and executed `npm run start` on portal via ssh and cmd, but it was unsuccessful, suggesting that the nest command could not be executed, as described in my answer.

Comment: @Blair Holmes When i run "npm run start" in kudu console, it starts the app successfully. Any idea on how to route to "main.ts" file as that is the starting point for nest app.